# How to convert array of lists into a corpus of strings and the strings are multiplied by the number (example provided)

Tags: python, string, list, repeat

I have got the following array of lists.

`[array(['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'boy', '3']) array(['I', '1', 'am', 'a', 'girl', '1']) array(['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'non-binary', '2'])`

I would like to write a python code convert the arrays into a corpus where the text is multiply by the number i.e in this format:

`corpus  = [ "I am a boy boy boy", "I am a girl", "I am non-binary non-binary]`

How can I achieve that on Python? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
data = [['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'boy', '3'], ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'girl', '1'], ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'non-binary', '2']]

def stringify(lst): # function: convert list into str with the words repeated
    repeated = [' '.join([lst[i]] * int(lst[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
    return ' '.join(repeated)

output = [stringify(x) for x in data] # apply the function for each item
print(output) # ['I am a boy boy boy', 'I am a girl', 'I am non-binary non-binary']
```

This one is basically applying list comprehension and `join` method repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

```
def corpus(list):
    s = []
    for x in range(len(list)):
        if not list[x].isdigit():
            if (x != len(list)-1) and (list[x+1].isdigit()):
                for num in range(int(list[x+1])):
                    s.append(list[x])
            else:
                s.append(list[x])
    return ' '.join(s)
```

This should check if there is a digit after each index of the list and return the index multiplied by the digit with necessary spaces within it. Sorry if it is clunky, I tried to make it quickly. Let me know if you need clarification for any if/else statement.

EDIT: I spent some extra time on this so that the code isn't as clunky. Instead of adding in a space to the string each time and adjusting for the final addition, we use ' '.join() to add space between each entry.
Applying it to the lists you provided yields

```
a = [['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'boy', '3'],
     ['I', '1', 'am', 'a', 'girl', '1'],
     ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'non-binary', '2']]

print(list(map(corpus,a)))

['I am a boy boy boy', 'I am a girl', 'I am non-binary non-binary']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to get all the words and then another list comprehension to 'flatten' the list.

```py
data = [['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'boy', '3'], 
        ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'girl', '1'], 
        ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'non-binary', '2']]

corpus = [[word]*int(sentence[pos+1]) for sentence in data for pos, word in enumerate(sentence) if pos % 2 == 0]

corpus = [word for words in corpus for word in words]

print(corpus)

""" OUTPUT
['I', 'am', 'a', 'boy', 'boy', 'boy', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'girl', 'I', 'am', 'non-binary', 'non-binary']
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

One option via `zip`:

```
l = [['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'boy', '3'], ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'girl', '1'], ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'non-binary', '2']]
result = [' '.join((' '.join([x] * int(y))) for x,y in zip(i[::2], i[1::2])) for i in l]
```

`Output`:

```
['I am a boy boy boy', 'I am a girl', 'I am non-binary non-binary']
```

Comment: @Acccumulation added initial list `l` you can run and let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your data:

1. `array` is not defined.
2. There's a `)` at the end, but no `(` at the end.
3. There aren't any commas between the elements in the outer list.
4. In the middle list, there aren't numbers after 'am' or 'a'.
5. From a stylistic point of view, you should have carriage returns between your lists.

Putting this together, I have the following:

```
my_list = [
    ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'boy', '3'],
    ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'a', '1', 'girl', '1'],
    ['I', '1', 'am', '1', 'non-binary', '2']
 ]
```

Given this input, the following code works:

```
[
    " ".join([" ".join([word]*int(count)) 
              for word, count in zip(sublist[::2],sublist[1::2])])
    for sublist in my_list
]
```